# Is it possible to trigger one lambda function with API Gateway, but to sent response from another one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, serverless

Basically, the idea is:

1) API Gateway -> lambda -> SQS -> lambda -> SQS -> lambda -> API Gateway response

or

2) API Gateway -> lambda -> lambda -> ... -> lambda -> API Gateway response

or

smth similar

---

The main concern is that the first lambda should not wait for anything it should die and response should come from another lambda or services.

---

I've read that API Gateway is synchronous, but mb there is some way.

Would be great to collect opinions, I think it would be useful for somebody.

Comment: What is your use case? Are you facing issue with API gateway 30 sec timeout?

Comment: It's just POC. One possible use case, imho, when you need synchronous REST API, but internally AWS Lambda functions communicate asynchronously (through SQS as an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main concern is that the first lambda should not wait for anything
>   it should die and response should come from another lambda or
>   services.

No, that's not possible with AWS API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to have immediate success response when you have verified that's all data you need to get the task done.

Then it can go something like this.

API Gateway -> (here you check data inputs and return success)lambda -> SQS -> lambda -> SQS -> lambda -> Webhook for acknowledgement

This will make sure that everything runs asynchronously and you can have some processing mechanism after the task is completed.